# Date() in web.archive.org

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Use `new Date()` in a web.archive.org saved paged returns the date of the snapshot.

Example: in [this case](https://web.archive.org/web/20050204022525/http://g1.com/) `new Date()` returns to me

```
Date Fri Feb 04 2005 00:26:15 GMT-0200 (Brasilia Summer Time)
```

Why this happens? And how can i get the current date instead?

Comment: The website fails to load. --- Edit: it's because they have overwritten the global date object.

Comment: Thanks! 
So is not possible get the current date in this case, using a simple script running on ViolentMonkey, for example?

Comment: What's violentmonkey?

Comment: You can't guarantee that `new Date()` on the client returns the correct date or time since those settings are (most likely) beyond your control and may not be accurate.